# VB If number is integer Then write it Else don´t show anything, How can I do?

Tags: vb.net, integer

I have this...

```
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim isn As Decimal
    Dim fsn As Decimal
    Dim inc As Decimal

    For m = isn To fsn Step inc
        Dim r As String = x * m
        If r.Contains(".") Then
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(r)
        End If
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
```

... but the program just do nothing... what can I do?? Please help me!!

Comment: you have to give the value for `x`,`isn`,`fsn`,`inc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `console.ReadLine` to get value from the user

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x As Integer = Console.ReadLine
    Dim isn As Decimal = Console.ReadLine
    Dim fsn As Decimal = Console.ReadLine
    Dim inc As Decimal = Console.ReadLine
    For m = isn To fsn Step inc
        Dim r As Double = x * m
        Dim r_string As String = r.ToString
        If r_string.Contains(".") Then
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(r)
        End If
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: ... the variables are a Console.ReadLine() user input

Comment: @AlfonsoUlisesMoctezumaGómez no problem bro, don't forget to vote the answer and accept it too

Comment: Someone vote down your answer and I vote up... but this changed the number to zero... But your code is simple and very useful to me!

Comment: it's okay, i'm glad i could help u :)

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to achieve this, I commented out other validations in my code to achieve this as well.

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim isn As Decimal
Dim fsn As Decimal
Dim inc As Decimal

For m = isn To fsn Step inc
    Dim r As String = x * m
    If Not r = int(r) Then 'If IsNumeric(r) = true AndAlso r.ToString().Contains(".") = true OrElse Math.Floor(value) = Math.Ceiling(value) OrElse Integer.TryParse(number, output) Then
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(r)
    End If
Next
Console.ReadLine()
```